# SVD low-rank matrix factorization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. I want to express $A$ in terms of its low-rank factorization $UV^\top$ for some $V\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times k}$, $U\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times k}$.

This translates in solving the solution to the following problem
$$
\min_{U,V} f(U,V) = \|A-UV^\top\|_F^2.
$$
I know the solution is expressed in terms of the SVD of $A$ but I want to derive it myself.

Setting the gradients to zero we get:

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial U} = UV^T V − AV = 0
$$
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial V} = VU^T U − A^T U = 0
$$

I cannot retrieve the svd solution from the above equations. Any idea on how to solve it?

Comment: I am quite sure there does not exist a unique solution. We need extra constraints on $U$ and $V$ to get something unique. Maybe you can try and express the low-rank condition somehow? An extra regularization term?

Comment: The low rank condition is expressed in U and V?

Comment: How about the "thin" SVD, i.e. $A = X \Sigma Y^T$ where $X \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times k}, \Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times k}$ and diagonal, $Y \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$. Then you can construct $U,V$ which makes $f = 0$ (for example just set $U=X \Sigma$ and $V=Y$). They are not unique though.

Comment: That may work. If you elaborate a bit on the comment and add a question I can accept it if nobody comes up with a better answer. Thanks